# Can't deploy my slash commands Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

- EDIT: turns out i was still on node 16.4.4 and this was the issue, slash commands require node 16.6 or higher. This happened because i switched machines and had my node_modules folder added to the git i was using.

Running my `guild.commands.js` or `deploy-commands.js` yields this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../common'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\discordBot\node_modules\discord-api-types\payloads\v9\index.js
- C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\discordBot\node_modules\discord-api-types\v9.js
- C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\discordBot\deploy-commands.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Documents\\discordBot\\node_modules\\discord-api-types\\payloads\\v9\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Documents\\discordBot\\node_modules\\discord-api-types\\v9.js',
  ]
}
```

I have set the scope to `application.commands` and `bot` and i have given the bot all the permissions. My first slash command is working properly but i simply cannot add new ones. I have tried node 16.4 and 17.4 and tried reinstalling everything from node to discord.js. It is always the same error with the common module. I am following this tutorial: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#individual-command-files

this is `deploy-commands.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow :) Could you please add the error message / stack trace as actual text and not as image? :D

Answer (score 0):

my deploy script is pretty much the same and works just fine. From the error message `Cannot find module '../common'` it looks like a require error.

I don't see a common require in you code example. Try finding that require and check your path with variations such as `'./common'` or `'common'` (if you don't know where it is you can run a project search with Ctrl + Maj + F)

It could be a file or a folder that was moved without refactoring.

I hope that's useful.